# How To Add Dates Under Notes In OneNote 2010

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I just want to ask how do I make OneNote automatically add a timestamp everytime I add a new note on a page, same as the one on it's title?

Are there software out there that could do this, other than OneNote? I want to be able to post when I finish something so that I know my timeline.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This is me. I found that you couldn't do it automatically, but you could add a timestamp to every post by clicking

**Alt + Shift + F** for the timestamp,
**Alt + Shift + T** for just the time,
or
**Alt + Shift + D** for just the date.

Thanks. ^^